# extract names substring using openrefine

Tags: openrefine

using openrefine, i need to achieve the following:

in a given column with people's names,

i must extract all content before the last dot (.) into a new column named **firstname**.

By extraction, i mean move the data, so that the initial column does not contain what is already moved to the **firstname** column.

On a second pass, i need to remove from the **names** column, and move to the firstname column,  everything that follows what is after the (,) comma. How would you approach this?

Example

```
names column         | lastname        | firstname
M., E. Handman       | Handman         | M., E. 
Surrey, Sam Bill     | Surrey          | Sam Bill
```

My effort is trying to make it work with something like:

```
value.find(/(\b\w{1}\W{1,})/).join('').trim()
```

Comment: Please, show the code you tried, so someone could help you

Comment: I suggest that you try to understand the answer given [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrefine/Bh10JNa7FNg), which is very very close to your actual problem.

Comment: A problem in your example is that the `names` column contains values with a mixed first / last name order.